# how do i transfer my account from admob to adsense?

Tags: android, adsense

a note on the admob page suggests that admob is stopping(?) and developers must start using adsense instead.

[image: admob note]

i am already signed up for an adsense account, but i cant seem to find a way to use adsense to create ads for mobile apps.

a link [here](https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-mobile-apps/docs/android/#afma-usingsdk) gives kind of a walkthrough for integration of the adsense sdk for android apps, but it requires the GoogleAdView.jar file which google does not distribute publicly and i cannot find anywhere to download.

what am i missing here?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should post this on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry about that, I will use Android Enthusiasts in the future for non programming related questions, thank you for the link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admob is stopping for Mobile websites, for apps it's still going.

> We are simplifying our suite of products by transitioning AdMob mobile
>   publishers to Google AdSense. Starting May 1, 2012 support for mobile
>   web sites on AdMob will be discontinued and you must have a Google
>   AdSense account to monetize mobile web sites.

Comment: OK, you are correct, I knew i was missing something... i found on this site: http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1678439 they mention:  App developers should continue to head to www.admob.com to monetize, measure and promote mobile apps. Mobile web publishers can get started with AdSense by signing up for free at www.google.com/adsense.

Thanks!